# Multiple API Queries in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am new to Power Query and have just learned how to pull in data from an external API using it.  The thing is, that I actually need to make multiple calls to the same API.  For example:

- http:://my-external-api.com/get-data/set-one?api_key=1234
- http:://my-external-api.com/get-data/set-two?api_key=1234
- http:://my-external-api.com/get-data/set-three?api_key=1234
- Etc.

In theory, this is how I imagine accomplishing this:

Step #1: Create an array of all the sets of data I want for my api.
E.g., `setData = ['set-one', 'set-two', 'set-three', ...]`

Step #2:  Create a URL with a variable in it.
E.g., `url = "http:://my-external-api.com/get-data/" & setVar & "?api_key=1234"`

Step #3:  Loop through this array and URL variable, outputting the data into Power Query.

The thing is, being new to Power Query I do not know how to do this.  I have learned a bit of the basics of M Code, but I still am having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

3. List item

Comment: One way to create loops is by using `List.Accumulate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of looping in PQ ranging from recursive functions to List.Generate(). In this case, I would go with List.Generate() and there is an excellent guide here:

https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate/

Comment: Thanks -- very helpful.  I should add that your guide plus another video by him got me started.  Here is a link to that other video:  https://youtu.be/a_RJzoj1cnM

Comment: Yes, he's a great teacher for PQ and highly recommended.